# Sip Error on Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, asterisk, sip

Hi actually Am trying to Create an application that works with Sip And Asterisk Communication but when i was trying to run this application on my devices it's Working fine but if it tried by Using The Android Emulator It shows me an error kindly Please help Me To Solve this error

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public SipProfile me = null;
    public SipProfile.Builder builder = null;
    public SipManager mSipManager = null;
    public String sipaddress = null;
    public String username = "17772146242101";
    public String domain = "callcentric.com";
    public String password = "Gjmurugan2!";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        if (mSipManager == null) {
            mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
        }

    }
        public void Register(View v)
        {
            try {
                builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
                builder.setPassword(password);
                me = builder.build();
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setAction("android.sipexample.INCOMING_CALL");
                PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
                try {
                    mSipManager.open(me, pi, null);
                } catch (SipException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            try {
                mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {

                    public void onRegistering(String arg0) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Registering with SIP Server...");
                    }

                    public void onRegistrationDone(String arg0, long arg1) {
                        Log.d("Connection Ready", "Ready For Communication");
                    }

                    public void onRegistrationFailed(String arg0, int arg2, String arg1) {
                        Log.d("Error Code", Integer.toString(arg2));
                        Log.d("Error Message", arg1);
                    }
                });
            } catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        // closeLocalProfile();

    private void closeLocalProfile() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mSipManager == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (me != null) {
                mSipManager.close(me.getUriString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sipreg.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
    android:onClick="Register"
    android:text="Register-Sip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here Comes My error in Logcat

```
01-05 23:58:43.997: D/AndroidRuntime(1069): Shutting down VM
01-05 23:58:43.997: W/dalvikvm(1069): threadid=1: thread exiting with    uncaught exception (group=0xb4a27ba8)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): Process: com.example.sipreg,   PID: 1069
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): java.lang.IllegalStateException:  Could not execute method of the activity
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     ... 11 more
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.example.sipreg.MainActivity.Register(MainActivity.java:52)
01-05 23:58:44.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     ... 14 more
01-05 23:58:45.777: I/Process(1069): Sending signal. PID: 1069 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` check `username, domain` having value or not

Comment: actually i have done an same thing by using my mobile device it's working fine but if i try to run the same application without modifying the source it will show the above error

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say this was `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.sipreg.MainActivity.Register(MainActivity.java:52)` but I'm not a Java programmer.

Comment: Thank you @miken32 i tried that too but i could not able to run on my android emulator,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some emulators do not support SIP, even if the API is supported.

Thus, SipManager.newInstance may return null: check this first!

sidenote: it would help if we clearly know what is line 52 in your MainActivity.java file!

Comment: Ya your correct today only i find that any emulator won't support for Sip Process by using the link of Developer.android community Thank you For Your Answer